# javascript program that reads name and age and display popup message when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner trying to learn javascript functions. I want to make a webpage that reads name and age and displays a popup message when the button is clicked this is my code. I tried different functions that have alert methods they worked fine but the one right here didn't can anyone tell me what's wrong with the function?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Q2 LAB2 </title>
     <script>

         
         function welcommsg() {
             var username = document.getElementById("name").value;;
             var userage = document.getElementById("age").value;;
             var ageINT

             ageINT = parseint(userage);
             

             if ( ageINT >= 18)
             {
                window.alert("welcome back" + username + "we missed you ");
             }
             else 
                window.alert("hello" + username + "we we are sorry . this website is for grown-ups only ");

         }

    
         
     </script>

</head>

<body>
    <p> please enter your name and age </p>
    <form>

        name : <input id="name" type="text" />
        age : <input id="age"  type="text"  />

        <button onclick="welcommsg();"> enter</button>

       

    </form>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Remove the form tags. When you click the button you submit the form and the page reloads. Also, it's `parseInt` not `parseint`

Answer (score 0):

This should work better. The form tag will reload the webpage whenever a button is clicked inside of it as it thinks you are submitting the form to a server. In this way, the alert isn't shown. I also made a few changes to the style and formatting which will come with time! This is great so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Q2 LAB2 </title>
     <script>
         function welcommsg() {
             var username = document.getElementById("name").value;
             var userage = document.getElementById("age").value;
             var ageINT;

             ageINT = parseInt(userage);
            
             if ( ageINT >= 18) {
                window.alert("welcome back " + username + " we missed you ");
             }
             else {
                window.alert("hello " + username + " we we are sorry . this website is for grown-ups only ");
             }
         }
     </script>

</head>

<body>
    <p> please enter your name and age </p>
        name : <input id="name" type="text" />
        age : <input id="age"  type="text"  />
        <button onclick="welcommsg()"> enter</button>
</body>


</html>
```